# Eclipse e4 RCP part activation event sent multiple times

Tags: eclipse, events, rcp, e4

In my Eclipse e4 RCP application, I'm using annotations to get notified when a Part is activated, using the approach proposed here : 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ModelEvents/article.html

```java
@Inject
@Optional
public void      subscribeTopicPartActivation(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.ACTIVATE)  Event event) {

  Object element = event.getProperty(EventTags.ELEMENT);
  if (!(element instanceof MPart)) {
    return;
  }

  MPart part = (MPart) element;

  System.out.println("Part activated: " + part.getLabel());
}
```

It works fine, but I've noticed that the activate event is triggered more than once for the same part in cases where we would expect a single activate event (i.e for exemple simple switch to the part...). The event message sent seems to be exactly the same (same target, same topic). Am I missing something ? Is it a normal behavior for the event framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears to be normal. There is a difference in the 'tags' value of the part between the two events. In the second event 'active' has been added to the tags.

This will show the difference:

```java
 System.out.println("part " + part.getElementId() + " tags " +
            part.getTags().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

You can also use the `EPartService` `addPartListener` method to listen for just part changes.

Comment: Thank you Greg. Sometimes we have 3 activate events (one with no tag as you mention, and two with the activate tag...). Which is strange anyway.

Comment: As far as I can see the only place this event is generated is in `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl` (the implementation of `EPartService`) in the internal `activate` method. You would have to trace through the code to see exactly how this works.